# how to remove junk characters in file the data looks like this

Tags: python

[15;1Runts/Jumbos        [16;1Errors Rx/Tx        [17;1Total Rx Pkts       [18;1      Tx Pkts       [19;1      Rx MBs        [20;1      Tx MBs        [21;1ARP/ICMP Pkts       [23;1Pattern Type        [24;1Tx Count/% Rate     [25;1PktSize/Tx Burst    [26;1Src/Dest Port

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this with regex replacement.

```
import re
string = '[15;1Runts/Jumbos [16;1Errors Rx/Tx [17;1Total Rx Pkts [18;1 Tx Pkts [19;1 Rx MBs [20;1 Tx MBs [21;1ARP/ICMP Pkts [23;1Pattern Type [24;1Tx Count/% Rate [25;1PktSize/Tx Burst [26;1Src/Dest Port'
print(re.sub('\[\d{1,2}\;\d','',string))
>>> 'Runts/Jumbos Errors Rx/Tx Total Rx Pkts  Tx Pkts  Rx MBs  Tx MBs ARP/ICMP Pkts Pattern Type Tx Count/% Rate PktSize/Tx Burst Src/Dest Port'
```